# express/jade get current user in view

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a simple nodejs/express application by [this](https://github.com/qed42/nodejs-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/app/views/includes/header.jade) example. In that view there is checking everyauth.loggedIn variable, but in my application I don't use everyauth module I use the following code instead:

```
req.session.auth = user;
```

How can I get access to  req.session.auth in a view in this case?

Comment: If you landed here and are using Express 3.0, here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580796/migrating-express-js-2-to-3-specifically-app-dynamichelpers-to-app-locals-use

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to use a `dynamicHelper` to expose anything in the session object (or the session object itself).  You can do something like this in your app.js:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  auth: function(req, res){
    return req.session.auth;
  }
});
```

Then in your views, you will have an `auth` variable that points to the session object.  For example:

```
You are logged in as <%= auth.name %>
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there in that approach any security issues?

Comment: It's just a helper method that is exposed to your views, so I can't think of any security concerns.  I would generally follow the rule of exposing only what I need, though.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some information, Scott's answer is the way to go to make the "auth" object available in all your views ([Express' Dynamic Helpers doc](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.dynamichelpers%28%29)), but if you only want to use it only in one specific view, you can pass it using the locals in the render method ([Express' res.render doc](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#res.render%28%29)):

```
res.render('yourView', { auth: req.session.auth });
```