# Migrating Express.js 2 to 3, specifically app.dynamicHelpers() to app.locals.use?

Tags: node.js, express

Updated Express.js from version 2 to 3, and the following call to `app.dynamicHelpers({..})` broke as it is no longer present in V3:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({

    request: function(req){
      return req
    },
    ...etc.
});
```

There's a [migration guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) which says this:

- `app.dynamicHelpers()` (use middleware + res.locals)

But I'm stumped how to do that.  Is there a more concrete example of how to migrate that?

Related SO post:  [nodejs express 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10204055/nodejs-express-3-0)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had the same problem with **session.user** and just fixed it by understanding that the app.use function needs to be **IN** the configure part, not where it was before.

Before:

```
app.configure();
app.dynamicHelpers({
  user: function(req, res) {
    return req.session.user;
  }
});
```

After:

```
app.configure(function(){
  //...
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.user = req.session.user;
    next();
  });
  //...
});
```

for Flash have a look at [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash)

Answer (score 6):

The solution with 16 votes is correct but be sure to use the `res.locals` assignment before 
`app.use(app.router);` refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/12597730/1132109

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the examples folder at github. For example [auth](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/examples/auth/app.js):

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  var err = req.session.error,
      msg = req.session.success;
  delete req.session.error;
  delete req.session.success;
  res.locals.message = '';
  if (err) res.locals.message = '<p class="msg error">' + err + '</p>';
  if (msg) res.locals.message = '<p class="msg success">' + msg + '</p>';
  next();
});
```

You can then use the variable "message" in your template.

Answer (score 3):

reponse.locals.use is a new useful feature of Express that lets you send a variable to your model that first needs to be evaluated. Say, for example, you want to send 3 variables to your view, all of which have to come after a request to a mongodb. The "old" way was to nest 3 callbacks, and when the last one returned you would render your view. locals.use makes this a heck of a lot easier as it will evaluate your functions and will render your view only when all have been evaluated.

Here's a short snippet of code on how to use them (this is coffee-script, hopefully you can convert it to javascript :D)

```
response.locals.use (request, response, done) ->
    myAsynchMethod (value) ->
        reponse.locals.myProperty = value
        done()
```

In this case, there will be a variable named myProperty you can use on your view that has it's value set to whatever myAsynchMethod gave the callback.

Comment: where would you use response.local.use? is it defined in the app.js or in the route hanlder(req,res)->..if so when to call the render...