# ExpressJS 3.0 How to pass res.locals to a jade view?

Tags: node.js, session, express, response, pug

I want to display a flash message after a user fails to sign in but I just can't get the variables to show up in my Jade views.

I have some pieces, I know I have to use this in my app.configure():

```
    app.use (req, res, next) ->
      res.locals.session = req.session
```

And I'll set what the flash message is after the user POSTS the wrong password:

```
     exports.postSession = (req, res) ->
       users = require '../DB/users'
       users.authenticate(req.body.login, req.body.password, (user) ->
       if(user)
         req.session.user = user
         res.redirect(req.body.redirect || '/')
       else
         req.session.flash = 'Authentication Failure!'
         res.render('sessions/new', {title:'New', redirect: req.body.redirect })
      )
```

I don't know how to access `res.locals.session` in my Jade file. I doubt I am setting everything up right. This question is a lot like this one: [Migrating Express.js 2 to 3, specifically app.dynamicHelpers() to app.locals.use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11580796/migrating-express-js-2-to-3-specifically-app-dynamichelpers-to-app-locals-use) but I still can't get it to work. It would be much appreciated if someone could show me just a simple example of setting values in res.local and accessing them in a view.

p.s. I do know about connect-flash but I need to understand how to make things available in views.

This is my app:

```
app.configure(() -> 
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
  app.set('view engine', 'jade')
  app.use(express.bodyParser())
  app.engine('.jade', require('jade').__express)
  app.use(express.methodOverride())
  app.use(express.cookieParser())
  app.use(express.session({ store: new express.session.MemoryStore({reapInterval: 50000 * 10}), secret: 'chubby bunny' }))
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))
  app.use((req, res, next) ->
    res.locals.session = req.session
    next()
  )
  app.use(app.router)
)
```

Comment: p.p.s Also where is the documentation for this? I've been looking at [Migration guide](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x), the [Express site](http://expressjs.com/api.html), and [Connect website](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) yet I still can't figure it out... Maybe its just me but I feel like I'm struggling to learn ExpressJS because its documentation is so sparse.

Comment: you can't access it as `session.flash`?

Comment: When i do this in jade: `- if(session.flash)` it gives me an error that says session is not defined.. But there is nothing off about how i set things up above?

Comment: is your app.use about app.router or app[VERB]?

Comment: i don't know the distinction between app.use being about app.router or app[VERB]. In my head its for the router as in these statements in app.use are evaluated against the immediate state of the server before a request gets routed... im not sure what app.use means in the context of app[VERB].

Comment: app[VERB] is anything like app.get app.post. these are all routes within app.use(app.router), which should be after any other `app.use` except any error handlers. what order are you putting them in?

Comment: Oh Ok, my app.use(app.router) is definitely after my `app.use (req, res, next) ->
      res.locals.session = req.session`. So beyond the order of my app.use() statements, is this basically the way to create res.local variables? Also, I'm trying to access these res.local variables in my layout file. i don't think this is the problem, but are there restrictions on which views have access to your res.locals??

Comment: no there are not. can you just post your app?

Comment: OK I posted my app. app.use(app.router) is below all of the middleware statements.

Comment: remove `app.engine`. see what happens. you don't need it since you already did `app.set('view engine', 'jade')`

Comment: Hey Jonathan. Thanks for your replies, I managed to fix my issue because I realized that I was doing redirect like this: `res.redirect('sessions/new',{title: 'New'})` I'm not even sure why that even brought the page up but res.redirect is supposed to be used like this now: `res.redirect([code,] url)` Anyways, stupid mistake on my part, thanks again for your attention.

Comment: lol that wasn't in your code. and yeah a redirect should never have an object either.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Just to give a short summary for everyone who has the same problem and got the impression that is was solved changing `res.redirect`.

It is very important to put your `app.use` middleware **before** `app.router`. See the comments by TJ Holowaychuck, the author of express

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/express-js/72WPl2UKA2Q/dEndrRj6uhgJ

Here is an example using a fresh installation of express v3.0.0rc4

app.js:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  res.locals.variable = "some content";
  next();
})

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title}
  p= variable
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for this. Disregard the comments underneath the question, this is the fix.

Comment: glad that I could help! do you want to officially accept the answer?

Comment: putting the app.use before the app.router passes the locals values properly in the views.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using express.session() you must call your function **AFTER** *express.session()* but **BEFORE** *app.router*, inside of app.configure().

app.js

```
app = express();

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.session());

  // Give Views/Layouts direct access to session data.
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
  });

  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

index.jade

```
extends layout

block content   
  h1= title   
  p My req.session.var_name is set to #{session.var_name}
```

Comment: Whats the reason behind this ?

Comment: I'm currently using it before express.session(), why should it be avoided?