# Node.js - How can I use my local variable with EJS view

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, ejs

I try to used my local variable on EJS. It's just a varaiable to check if the user is connected.
-> Like the last post on this link:
[How to know if user is logged in with passport.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739725/how-to-know-if-user-is-logged-in-with-passport-js)

So,

**app.js**

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
    next();
});
```

**view EJS**

```
<% if (login) { %>
      <div id="subMenuUser">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            </span>Menu<span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Menu Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Menu Item 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
 <% } %>
```

**I get an error:**

```
login is not defined
```

I would like to use this variable with all view.. possible ?

Before this method, I sent each time my variable in render like that:

```
res.render('ad/index', { login: req.session.user });
```

Comment: I haven't used EJS but maybe something like login = typeof(req.session.use) != 'undefined' ? req.session.use : { } will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you are declaring that middleware function that sets res.locals.login before you declare your app.router. This ensures that the route rendering your template does not render the template before your middleware can set res.locals.login. Something along the lines of:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.locals.login = req.isAuthenticated();
    next();
});

app.configure(function(){
    ...
    app.use(app.router);
    ...
});
```

It appears others have asked a similar question, but with other templating engines: [Accessing res.locals from Backbone.Router templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150826/accessing-res-locals-from-backbone-router-templates)

Answer (score 7):

or if you want to do without creating Middleware, you can also directly use following check in your ejs file:

```
if(locals.login) { .... }
```