# Special parameter for render in Express

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I use Jade for rendering templates. It looks like this:

```
res.render('template_name', {var1: 'One', var2: 'Two'})
```

But I need that each render add one parameter, which is the result of the function. Example. I write

```
res.render('template_name', {var1: 'One', var2: 'Two'})
```

But it reads like

```
res.render('template_name', {var1: 'One', var2: 'Two', var3: func()})
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to add a middleware before all routes that you want to access `var3`, like this;

```
function populateLocals(req, res, next){
  res.locals.var3 = function() {
    return "alalao";
  };

  next();
}

app.use(populateLocals);
```

You can add specific values to locals on a route basis by doing it individually like this;

```
app.get('/', populateLocals, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('foo', {a: 1, b: 2});
});

app.get('/whatever', populateLocals, function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('foo', {a: 1, b: 2});
});
```

Also, have a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12550067/91403)