# I can use app.locals directly in templates but not res.locals

Tags: node.js, express

In my Express application, I'm able to set `app.locals` and use them directly in my templates (rendered using [express-handlebars](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars)). However, when I set `res.locals` in middleware, they are not available unless I pass them in. Am I doing something wrong?

**Server**

```
app.locals.foo = "foo";
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.bar = "bar";
  next();
});
```

**Template**

```
{{foo}} {{bar}}
```

**Test 1**

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  app.render("template.html", {}, function(error, html) {
    res.send(html);
  });
});
```

*Result*

```
foo
```

**Test 2**

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  app.render("template.html", {bar: res.locals.bar}, function(error, html) {
    res.send(html);
  });
});
```

*Result*

```
foo bar
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ExpressJS 3.0 How to pass res.locals to a jade view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550067/expressjs-3-0-how-to-pass-res-locals-to-a-jade-view)

Comment: @RobertMoskal Nope. `app.router` is deprecated in 4.x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`res.locals` is available in `res.render`. I suspect you are calling `app.render` by mistake, and should be calling `res.render`.

Comment: That's it! I didn't realize there was a difference between using `app.render` and `res.render`.

Answer (score 0):

The app.locals are available in the entire application as long as the application is up. The res.locals only exists during the request.

Comment: Correct, which is why I set them in the middleware.