# putting User data in all routes if authenticated Express/Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I'm wondering if there is a way to put user data available in session, in response of routes by default. For example writing something like this:

```
app.get("/someRandomPath",PutUserData,function(req,res,next)
{
  res.render("myView",{title:"my page title"})
}

function PutUserData(req,res,next)
{
  if(auth)
  {
   res.send({user:session.user}
   next()
  }
  else next()
}
```

or even better do something in application level such as `app.use(...)` ?
The reason I want to do this is I want to avoid checking if user is Authed or not in every single route and render views with different data.
I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `res.locals` from the Express documentation.  That could work for you.

http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550067/expressjs-3-0-how-to-pass-res-locals-to-a-jade-view) for help understanding how res.locals works.

```
 app.use(function(req, res, next){
   res.locals.user = session.user;
   next();
 });
```

front-end (jade template but you can use whatever templating engine you want)

```
extends layout

block content   
  p user was set to #{user}
```

Comment: You're right.  I have updated my answer.  Try looking into that.