# Using session variables in jade template in node js

Tags: node.js, pug, express

is there any alternate for using session variables in jade template file other than using dynamic helper function and passing it through res.render? 
if i use dynamichelpers method its showing error since it is deprecated. please help

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
            res.locals.user = "xxxx";
            next(); 
        });
```

i used this code in app.js inside app.configure function. but still i couldn't use the variable user in my view. do i need to install any additional packages or any other code?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11580796

Comment: yes thanku, but still am unable to access that variable.

Comment: Are you including the custom middleware before `app.use(app.router)`? If after `app.router`, you'll want to reverse their order.

Comment: yes that was the mistake i made. thanku so much jonathan lonowski

Answer (score 1):

This code should work. For example, I'm using nearly identical code in one of my production systems:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    app.locals.token = req.session._csrf;
    app.locals.user = req.user;
    ...
    next();
});
```

You'll need to make sure this code is *after* you set req.locals.user - for example, if you are using Passport, after you do the initialize and session code, but *before* you actually handle and render the request.

Comment: What is the purpose of next() in this case? I know it can be useful for user authentication functions, but if you are just setting app.locals do we need next()? I removed next() and it still works fine without it.

Comment: The next() call, without an error, indicates that this middleware is complete but further middleware needs to be executed as well. If you do not call next(), I don't believe any further middleware is executed.

Comment: I think you only need next if you want to pass something on to the next piece of middleware. 'Use' adds the next func in the chain to be called. Next gives it an argument.